# Save output of a for loop for a future use in the code

Tags: python-3.x

I want to repeat n times a routine with a for loop and save the output in a list. My code is the following:

```
n = 4
N =  3
DX_1 = n*[np.zeros((N,2))]
empirical_b1 = [np.zeros(n)]
y = [np.zeros(n)]

def data(n=1):
    for i in range(n):
        Gamma = np.random.uniform(-0.5*np.pi, 0.5*np.pi, (2,N))
        W = np.random.exponential(1, (2,N))
        DX_1[i] = pow(dt, 1/a1)*(np.sin(a1*Gamma))/ pow(np.cos(Gamma),1/a1)* \
             pow((np.cos((1-a1)*Gamma))/W, (1-a1)/a1)
    return DX_1
DX_1 =  data(n = 4)

U1 = np.array([[np.sqrt(N)], [np.sqrt(N)]])

def vector(U1):
    return np.matmul(U1.reshape(1,2), DX_1)
v = vector(U1)
# with the following loop I expect to get a list with n elements.
for x in v:
    empirical_b1 = np.sum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1)*x))/N
    print(empirical_b1)
```

In the last loop I get the results which I want. But if I print the empirical_b1 outside the loop I get only one element not n as I desire and I want to use this output later in the code. I would like to save this output (n elements) in  a list so I can use it later in the code. Could please anyone have an idea how I could possible do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list and append the results:

```
empirical_b1_list = []
for x in v:
    empirical_b1_list.append(np.sum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1)*x))/N)
print(empirical_b1_list)
```

Or use list comprehension

```
empirical_b1_list = [np.sum(np.exp(np.complex(0,1)*x))/N for x in v]
print(empirical_b1_list)
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is working @Jay . So the idea is to create an empty list and then append this with the routine that I want to use?

Comment: Yes. Either that or use the list comprehension method.  Both will work. Please consider upvoting the answer too if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: I tried also comprehension list and it works as well @jay thanks!